# Is there a Silverlight LINQ-to-OData translater that can be used with Web API?

Tags: linq, silverlight, asp.net-web-api, wcf-data-services, odata

I am attempting to build a Silverlight application that talks to an ASP.NET Web API, however Web API doesn't provide the same client-side proxies as WCF Data Services making LINQ to OData a challenge.  Is there a way to manually build client-side proxies similar to those used by WCF Data Services but that talk to Web API instead?

And before any one asks, the reason I'm not simply using WCF Data Services is because it doesn't appear to play nice with EF's DbGeometry type which is a deal breaker for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WCF Data Services client should work fine with Web API - it's just a vanilla OData client.

Comment: Could you provide a link to some instructions on how to do that?  I'm only aware of the Add Service Reference method of generating client-side proxies and that seems to only work with WCF Data Services, not Web API.

Comment: Add Service Reference is exactly what you'd want to do; it *should* work with any OData service that exposes $metadata in the right location.